Desplegar Front-Back end en un mismo servidor
Buen día,
Necesito desplegar 2 proyectos que recien terminé, el 'front' está hecho en ANGULAR v16 y el 'back' (que es solo una API) está hecho en LARAVEL 10, el Servidor de 'producción' es un UBUNTU 22.04 al cuál he desplegado un APACHE + MYSQL + PHP. El proyecto de ANGULAR lo he desplegado directamente en el /VAR/WWW/HTML/ y el proyecto de LARAVEL lo he desplegado en una carpeta nombrada BCK_INTEGRADOR.
Dentro de los SITES-AVAILABLES se encuentran 2 archivos '.conf':

El '000-default.conf', que es el que se ha generado al instalar el APACHE y que me imagino es el que se encarga de que el FRONT se pueda cargar de forma correcta al realizar la petición en el navegador a la IP del Server.
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>


El 'bck_integrador.conf', que es el 'directorio virtual' que he generado para que el APACHE lo reconozca como 'un subdominio' y que pueda responder el BACK a las peticiones del FRONT.
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName 154.53.58.69
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bck_integrador/public

  <Directory /var/www/html/bck_integrador>
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bckapi-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bckapi-access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>



El problema se presenta con las peticiones a la API, el navegador responde que no existen las rutas que se definieron en el ROUTES del proyecto, siendo que en el ambiente de desarrollo, mi maquina, sin problema funcionan ambas, ¿Que podre estar haciendo mal?
De antemano gracias por el apoyo.

hola, revisa que el apache tenga habilitado PHP ya que no viene por default.

si, una de las pruebas que se realizan al empezar a configurar es esa, que el motor de php este ligado al apache
